# MQTT Performance on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mqtt

I'm using XCode 9.2 with Swift 4 on an iPad Air 2 and I try to receive real-time data over MQTT (I already tested [CocoaMQTT](https://github.com/emqtt/CocoaMQTT) and [LightMQTT](https://github.com/PasiSalenius/LightMQTT)).

I subscribed to a topic from which I receive around 5-10 byte buffers per second.
Unfortunately, **there are lag spikes** while receiving the data. For example, 6 byte buffers are received very fluently and after that nothing comes through for about one or two seconds.
I tested it already with MQTTSpy but there aren't any lag spikes.

I set QoS to `.qos0` and the process is running within `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`. Is there something I can do to receive the data more fluently?

Comment: On what network?

Comment: I would use a high priority background queue rather than the main queue. There can be a lot going on on the main queue; hi updates etc.  iOS is not an RTOS though so you can’t get guaranteed real time operation

Comment: @hardillb it's basically over the internet. (I just call a URI, but the latency should be fine).

Comment: @Paulw11 did you mean: `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {`?

Comment: yes, I would try that.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you very much. I think that fixed it but I had to change it directly in CocoaMQTT because they run it within the `Dispatch.main` queue by default.